# Replication of an intercept only GMM SAS example in R

Tags: r, self-study, generalized-moments

I try to replicate this SAS example in R: http://support.sas.com/kb/40/098.html I've done everything that's easy, but since I am not familiar with GMM, I am stuck with the last step.

Reproducible example:

```
#!/bin/R
# Replication of http://support.sas.com/kb/40/098.html

library(data.table)
library(sandwich)
library(lmtest)
library(gmm)

data <- matrix(c(
596.7, 90.9, 0.7167, 3.23,
637.7, 97.4, 0.7277, 3.55,
691.1, 113.5, 0.7436, 4.04,
756.0, 125.7, 0.7676, 4.5,
799.6, 122.8, 0.7906, 4.19,
873.4, 133.3, 0.8254, 5.16,
944.0, 149.3, 0.8679, 5.87,
992.7, 144.2, 0.9145, 5.95,
1077.6, 166.4, 0.9601, 4.88,
1185.9, 195, 1, 4.5,
1326.4, 229.8, 1.0575, 6.44,
1434.2, 228.7, 1.1508, 7.83,
1549.2, 206.1, 1.2579, 6.25,
1718, 257.9, 1.3234, 5.5,
1918.3, 324.1, 1.4005, 5.46,
2163.9, 386.6, 1.5042, 7.46,
2417.8, 423, 1.6342, 10.28,
2631.7, 401.9, 1.7842, 11.77,
2954.1, 474.9, 1.9514, 13.42,
3073.0, 414.5, 2.0688, 11.02), nrow = 20, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(gnp = data[, 1], investment = data[, 2], price.index = data[, 3], nominal.interest = data[, 4])

dt <- data.table(df)
dt[, rate := (price.index - shift(price.index, n = 1L, type = 'lag')) / shift(price.index, n = 1L, type = 'lag') * 100]

DT <- dt
DT[, real.investment := investment / price.index]
DT[, real.gnp := gnp / price.index]
DT[, real.interest.rate := nominal.interest - rate]

DT <- DT[complete.cases(DT)][, .(real.gnp, real.investment, real.interest.rate)]

summary(lm(real.investment ~ real.interest.rate + real.gnp, data = DT))
# Identical !

regression <- lm(real.investment ~ real.interest.rate + real.gnp, data = DT)

coeftest(regression, vcov = NeweyWest(regression, lag = 4, prewhite = FALSE))
# Identical !

regression.only.constant <- lm(real.investment ~ 1, data = DT)
summary(regression.only.constant)
# Identical ! (duh)

coeftest(regression.only.constant, vcov = NeweyWest(regression, lag = 4, prewhite = FALSE))

g1 <- DT$real.investment ~ 1
# then?
```

Any hints on replicating the last example with GMM, that corresponds to this SAS code?:

```
  proc model data=two;
     endo r_invest;
     instruments / intonly;
     parms b0;
     r_invest=b0;
     fit r_invest / gmm kernel=(bart,5,0) vardef=n;
     run; 
     quit;
```